# Same media folder for both WordPress sites?

Tags: wordpress, upload, media

It is possible, to use the same media (uploads) folder for both sites created on WordPress CMS?

For example, site.com and my.site.com, but last site on subdomain use uploads folder from main site - site.com/wp-content/uploads.

Comment: Find some info: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-custom-upload-dir/